# Open set in a product of colimits

Tags: general-topology, limits-colimits

Suppose that $X=\operatorname{colim} (A_1 \to A_2 \to \dots)$ and $Y=\operatorname{colim} (B_1 \to B_2 \to \dots)$, where $A_i$ and $B_j$ topological spaces. I want to prove that some set $U$ is open in $X\times Y$ iff $U$ is open in every $A_i \times B_j$. My attempt:

$U$ is open in $X\times Y$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $U=\bigcup _k V_k\times V_k^\prime$ for $V_k$ open in $X$ and $V_k^\prime$ open in $Y$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $V_k$ is open in $A_i$ and $V_k^\prime$ is open in $B_j$ ,$\forall k,i,j$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $V_k \times V_k ^\prime$ is open in $A_i\times B_j$, $\forall k,i,j$

And I stuck there. The next step I wanted to do is to say $V_k \times V_k ^\prime$ is open in $A_i\times B_j$, $\forall k,i,j$ $\Leftrightarrow$ $\bigcup _k V_k\times V_k^\prime$ is an open subset of $A_i\times B_j$, but it's not true.

Any help? Maybe the statement is false?

Comment: To be clear, are you assumiing that the maps $A_i\to A_{i+1}$ and $B_i\to B_{i+1}$ are all inclusions of subspaces?

Comment: One can assume that $A_i$ has finer topology than $A_{i+1}$ has.

Comment: So, you're considering arbitrary sequential colimits?

Comment: It will be sufficient to assume that $A_i \to A_{i+1}$ is the continuous identity map and the same for $B_j\to B_{j+1}$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1256405/4280) would seem to be a counterexample (even when the second colimit is trivial).

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Wow, thanks!